# Equations in RMarkdown knit to html but not pdf or word

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr

I'm attempting to knit a set of equations in RMarkdown to both pdf and word. They work great in html, but not pdf or word. When I try to knit to pdf the error message says:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.241 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in PerceptionsTheftManuscript.Rmd. See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile PerceptionsTheftManuscript.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See PerceptionsTheftManuscript.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'knitr' was built under R version 4.1.3 
2: package 'rmarkdown' was built under R version 4.1.3 
3: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.1.3 
Execution halted
```

Here are the equations I am trying to produce:

```
\begin{equation}
\text{P}_{HurdleNegBinom}(y|\pi,\mu,\theta)= 
  \begin{cases} 

\pi, 
& y=0 \\ \\
(1-\pi) \cdot \text{P}_{ZeroTruncNegBinom}(y|\mu,\theta), & y>0 

\end{cases}
\end{equation}

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
  
\begin{equation}
\text{Y}_{ij} \sim HurdleNegBinom(\pi_{ij},\mu_{ij},\phi)  \\ \nonumber\\

\pi_{ij} = \frac{\text{exp}(\eta_{ij})}{1+\text{exp}(\eta_{ij})} \nonumber\\ \nonumber\\

\eta_{ij} = \alpha0^\eta+\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j}^\eta+\beta1^\eta\cdot\text{Theft}_{i}+
  \beta2^\eta\cdot\text{MangDecl}_{i}+\beta3^\eta\cdot\text{MangArea}_{i}+\nonumber\\ \beta4^\eta\cdot\text{REDD}_{i}+
  \beta5^\eta\cdot\text{Gender}_{i}+\beta6^\eta\cdot\text{CommitteeMemb}_{i}\nonumber\\ \nonumber\\

\mu_{ij} = 
  \text{exp}(\alpha0^\mu+\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j}^\mu+\beta1^\mu\cdot\text{Theft}_{i}+
               \beta2^\mu\cdot\text{MangDecl}_{i}+\beta3^\mu\cdot\text{MangArea}_{i}+\nonumber\\ \beta4^\mu\cdot\text{REDD}_{i}+
               \beta5^\mu\cdot\text{Gender}_{i}+\beta6^\mu\cdot\text{CommitteeMemb}_{i}) \nonumber\\ \nonumber\\


% \boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j} \sim Norm(0,\sigma) \nonumber
\end{equation}


<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
  
\begin{equation}

\text{Y}_{ij} \sim Poisson(\mu_{ij})  \\ \nonumber\\

\mu_{ij} = 
  \text{exp}(\alpha0+\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j}+\beta1\cdot\text{Theft}_{i}+
               \beta2\cdot\text{MangDecl}_{i}+\beta3\cdot\text{MangArea}_{i}+\nonumber\\ \beta4\cdot\text{REDD}_{i}+
               \beta5\cdot\text{Occupation}_{i}+\beta6\cdot\text{CommitteeMemb}_{i})

\end{equation}
```

When I run just the first equation it knits to pdf but not word.

Answer (score 0):

It might be failing due to `\\ \nonumber\\` and/or the spaces inside the equation. I can only help you with the pdf part. I recommend you to use the `align` environment, e.g.

```
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  #word_document: defaults
---


\begin{equation}
\text{P}_{HurdleNegBinom}(y|\pi,\mu,\theta)= 
  \begin{cases} 
\pi, 
& y=0 \\ \\
(1-\pi) \cdot \text{P}_{ZeroTruncNegBinom}(y|\mu,\theta), & y>0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
  
\begin{align}
\text{Y}_{ij} &\sim HurdleNegBinom(\pi_{ij},\mu_{ij},\phi)   \nonumber\\
\pi_{ij} &= \frac{\text{exp}(\eta_{ij})}{1+\text{exp}(\eta_{ij})}  \nonumber\\
\eta_{ij} &= \alpha0^\eta+\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j}^\eta+\beta1^\eta\cdot\text{Theft}_{i}+
  \beta2^\eta\cdot\text{MangDecl}_{i}+\beta3^\eta\cdot\text{MangArea}_{i}+\nonumber\\ &\beta4^\eta\cdot\text{REDD}_{i}+
  \beta5^\eta\cdot\text{Gender}_{i}+\beta6^\eta\cdot\text{CommitteeMemb}_{i} \nonumber\\
\mu_{ij}&= 
  \text{exp}(\alpha0^\mu+\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j}^\mu+\beta1^\mu\cdot\text{Theft}_{i}+
               \beta2^\mu\cdot\text{MangDecl}_{i}+\beta3^\mu\cdot\text{MangArea}_{i}+\nonumber\\ &\beta4^\mu\cdot\text{REDD}_{i}+
               \beta5^\mu\cdot\text{Gender}_{i}+\beta6^\mu\cdot\text{CommitteeMemb}_{i}) \nonumber\\ 
\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j} &\sim Norm(0,\sigma) \nonumber
\end{align}


&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
  
\begin{align}
\text{Y}_{ij} &\sim Poisson(\mu_{ij})   \nonumber\\
\mu_{ij} &= 
  \text{exp}(\alpha0+\boldsymbol{\beta0}_{j}+\beta1\cdot\text{Theft}_{i}+
               \beta2\cdot\text{MangDecl}_{i}+\beta3\cdot\text{MangArea}_{i}+\nonumber\\ &\beta4\cdot\text{REDD}_{i}+
               \beta5\cdot\text{Occupation}_{i}+\beta6\cdot\text{CommitteeMemb}_{i})
\end{align}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, the spaces were the issue. It now knits to pdf fine, but not Word. Thank you for the help!